# Compare two column values in two different tables and calculate the difference based on 24h cycle

Tags: mysql

> I have two tables asset_data and ticker_data. Symbol column in
>   asset_data needs to match with quoteAsset in table ticker_data.If
>   match found, calculate the price difference between lastPriceUSD in
>   the last 24 hours by using the createdAt stamp.
>
> Basically comparing the two prices of the same currency symbol in 24
>   hours cycle. eg. if the price of EUR on 2019-05-12 at 18:05 is 0.89,
>   need to c**ompare EUR with yesterday at the same time with 2019-05-11 at
>   18:05**
>
> **asset_data Table**

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| assetId | pair   | symbol | lastPriceUSD | createdAt           |
+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
|       1 | EURUSD | EUR    | 0.8900000000 | 2019-05-12 18:05:10 |
|       2 | AUDEUR | AUD    | 0.6500000000 | 2019-05-12 18:05:45 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
```

> **ticker_data Table**

```
+----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| tickerId | pair   | quoteAsset | lastPriceUSD | createdAt           |
+----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|        1 | USDEUR | EUR        | 0.9500000000 | 2019-05-11 18:06:40 |
|        2 | EURAUD | AUD        | 0.7500000000 | 2019-05-11 18:17:49 |
+----------+--------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
symbol     difference
 EUR         -6.00%
 AUD         -10.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables like this:

```
select 
  a.symbol,
  100.0 * (a.lastpriceusd - t.lastpriceusd) / a.lastpriceusd as difference
from asset_data a inner join ticker_data t
on t.quoteasset = a.symbol and (
    select min(createdat) from ticker_data 
    where quoteasset = a.symbol and 
    createdat between date_add(a.createdat, interval '-1' day) and a.createdat
  ) = t.createdat
```

The condition:

> compare EUR with yesterday at the same time with 2019-05-11 at 18:05

cannot be accurate if the 2 dates do not differ by **exactly** 1 day, so I use the minimum `createdat` from `ticker_data` that is greater than `createdat` - 1 day from `asset_data`

Comment: this does not return anything. I don't have data at the exact interval -1 day. I mean if I am checking between (NOW() - interval '-1' day) and a.createdAt
  ) = t.createdAt I dont have data available @=t.createdAt. can you please adjust the query to be flexible to look between NOW() - 1 day at the same time (+- 20 mins)